# Как сделать так, чтобы картинка фона выходила за пределы блока div?

Tags: css

Есть код:

```
      #sidebar_top_bgg{
      width:100px;
      height:100px;
      background-image: url(../img/header_top_bgg.png);
      background-position:top center;
      background-repeat:no-repeat; 
      }
```

Как сделать так, чтобы картинка фона выходила за пределы блока div?

Comment: Кажется, у вас ошибка в записи background-position:top center; Сначала указывается позиция по-горизонтали (left, center, right), а только после нее по-вертикали (top, center, bottom).

Comment: Кстати, на будущее... В стили присваивайте только классам. Никаких ID. Их лучше юзать для взаимодействия с JS, например.

Comment: Спасибо за советы,но проблема не решена:(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Никак. Только переместить ее в внутрь в еще один блок и уже сделать как вам нужно.

Comment: Все не так просто...вот код http://jsfiddle.net/1c20c7t7/

Речь идет о #sidebartop

Answer (score 1):

Никак. Однако, в моём случае, фоном был цвет и я добавил в свой div тень таким же цветом:

```
div.main {
    background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.8);
    box-shadow: 0 0 0 10px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.8);
    }
```

Более подробно здесь: http://htmlbook.ru/css3-na-primerakh/teni

Answer (score 0):

Зачем Вам это? Добавьте картинку внутрь DIVa,  блоку поставьте `position:relative`, картинке -`position:absolute...`, дальше позиционируйте, как хотите, картинку внутри блока.

http://www.myfirstsite.ru/notes/absolutnoe-pozicionirovanie-elementa-vnutri-roditelskogo

Answer (score 0):

Отрицательные margin попробуй, например, margin:0 -60px; в общем минус ставь, туда, куда надо фон